# What does "git clone /path/to/repository" do?

Tags: git, github, version-control, dvcs

I came across `git clone /path/to/repository` in my Git [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html). What does this command do and when will you use it?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It clone an already local repository in another directory. Except for tutorial/learning purpose, you will never do that but clone a remote repository. But to learn git pull/push workflow, that make a lot of sense!

Comment: @Philippe thank you for your explanation. It helped me understand the command and use case much better than the official guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there exists a repository at `/path/to/repository`, or in Windows-speak, `C:\path\to\repository`, then the commands

```
git clone /path/to/repository     # Linux, Unix, Cygwin
git clone C:\path\to\repository   # Windows CMD
git clone C:/path/to/repository   # Git-for-Windows's shell
```

create a copy of the repository in the new directory `repository` (in the current directory where you issued the `git` command). This copy treats the original at `/path/to/repository` as the "origin" repository, from which you can pull changes and to which you can push changes.

It is the same as if you had cloned a repository from some remote hosting site; it just so happens that the origin is located on your local disk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The command and use case is much clearer to me now.

Answer (score -1):

It clones a git repository into your desired local path.

Use it whenever you need to work with a git repository in your computer.

Comment: Please add more details to better explain this answer. A new user may not understand "it clones a git repository to your desired local path" much more than "git clone /path/to/repository"